# cell array of cell arrays

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-recognition

I am writing an Ear detection system and want to save acquired data into a text file ( enrollment data ). The data is a cell array that include cell arrays like this:

`V = {[1*1] [1*1] [1*1] [1*1] [1*1] {100*2} {4000*2} {2000*2}  }`

this data is for the first image enrolled, there are 5 different images which has to be entered into the database like vector above. I want to write these cell arrays into a text file and then import the data into MAT LAB in a way that after importing I'm gonna have a table in the import wizard like this :

[image]

(I need this table for classification )

now, my problem is that I don't know how to make such a table, I mean how should I write data in a text file that after importing a table like picture above will be produced. I tried different functions like dlmwrite, fprintf and save but didn't get the result. I'm very confused and as I'm almost new to MAT LAB  really look forward to your help.

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused. You're obtaining data from a MATLAB tool, saving it to a text file, then reading it into MATLAB again? If that's the case why not save it as a *.mat file?

Comment: This text file and table is going to work as my database to compare image data to saved data ( data that was extracted in the enrollment). After importing the variables in the table will be in workspace and I can use them in classification code. I searched about making databases for such systems in matlab and found this method. Isn't this gonna work ?

Comment: Are you using MATLAB to capture your data? Are you using MATLAB to process your data? If the answer to both of those questions is yes then I don't understand the desire to save the data to a text file. Can it be done? Yes. It will likely require you to write your own parser to read it back in properly.

Comment: the answer is yes, but can you help me with this problem?

Comment: The answer is not to save it as a text file. Use [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) to save the variable from your workspace as a *.mat file and load it later with [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html).